# connect to remote emacs session via ssh

Tags: ssh, server, x11

Unfortunately, I forgot to start the emacs-server at work, running on Linux. Is there now any option to connect to my remote graphical X11 emacs session via ssh?

Comment: What OS is running on the remote machine? If it is linux, is it running X? You might be able to use something like http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html to convince your emacs instance to do M-x server-start.

Comment: @icarus: It is Debian Linux, X is running. Nice idea, although I thought there might be a more direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is running on X, it might be possible to use a program like [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) , [xdo](https://github.com/baskerville/xdo), or [wmctrl](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/wmctrl/)

All these programs allow you to list windows, select one, and simulate typing on them.

Another approach would be to run [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) on the remote machine and connect to it with a local vnc viewer. The referenced manual page tells you how to forward needed ports using ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the direct question, but I suggest the following in your init file to prevent this from happening in future.

```el
;; Start server (but don't restart).
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

Alternatively (but still not helpful for your present situation), under the [FUBAR: Impossible to connect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc21) heading on the "Emacs As Daemon" EmacsWiki page, there's an ingenious approach to enabling a server start to be triggered with a process signal.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `ssh` access to the respective server at work you can start the emacs server at work using the command (with the respective username and server host name):

```
$ ssh -X myuser@myserver.work.domain emacs --daemon
```

EDIT: If your emacs is already started on the server than just kill it and add automatic server start in your .emacs:

```
$ ssh myuser@myserver.work.domain killall emacs
$ ssh myuser@myserver.work.domain sh -c "echo '(server-start)' >> ~/.emacs"
```

Now you can start emacs in daemon mode as described on the first command. The added server-start command would enable the server on the opened emacs session.

Comment: The question was about connecting to an *existing* emacs instance.

Comment: It is not clear from the question. The question states "I forgot to start the emacs-server". Anyone using emacs-server on a regular basis has it started automatically when emacs is started. So stating that emacs-server was not started sounds like emacs itself is closed.

Comment: Anyway, I edited my answer to address this case too.

Comment: * Down-voting my original answer (which was relevant for similar question of other users) is counter-productive...

Comment: The question text "Is there now any option to connect to my remote emacs session" is pretty clear -- they have a remote emacs session, and they wish to connect to it. *Killing* the remote session helps (for this particular question) even less.

Comment: Killing an emacs session makes no difference. A properly configured emacs would have desktop-save-mode enabled with a respective desktop-auto-save-timeout. In addition, all the files are automatically saved anyway. So after killing and restarting emacs (with the updated .emacs that includes server-start) one would be able to get a result which is identical to starting the server on the original emacs instance.

Comment: Desktop can't magically restore all of the inferior processes running inside Emacs, nor the non-file-visiting buffers which were associated with them (e.g. the output from various shells, REPLs, etc, etc). You cannot assume the people are only using Emacs to edit files.